# How to search in GridView using java?

Tags: java, android

i hope you are fine.

i have a small code and good way to Search in list, and the code work perfectly when i use it in listView

but in GidView don't work and i get Error

> Attenmp to invoque virtual methode 'int java.util.ArrayList.size() on
> a Null object referance

it is the same code im using to search in listview just in GridView i get this error, i hope you can suggest a help for me.

this is My code :

in my onCreate i have the String SavedToSearch take the listMap data

```
String SavedToSearch = new Gson().toJson(listMap);

 

searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                                              }

                                              @Override
                                              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                                              }

                                              @Override
                                              public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                                                ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> searchMap = new ArrayList<>();

                                                  try {

                                                      double length;
                                                      double r;
                                                      String value1;
                                                      listMap = new Gson().fromJson(SavedToSearch, new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>() {
                                                      }.getType());
                                                      length = listMap.size();
                                                      r = listMap.size() - 1;
                                                      for (int _repeat17 = 0; _repeat17 < (int) (length); _repeat17++) {
                                                          value1 = listMap.get((int) r).get("name").toString();
                                                          if (value1.toLowerCase().contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())) {

                                                          } else {
                                                              listMap.remove((int) (r));
                                                          }
                                                          r--;
                                                      }
                                                      gridview1.setAdapter(new Gridview1Adapter(listMap));


                                                  } catch (Exception r10) {
                                                      r10.printStackTrace();
                                                  }

                                              }
                                          });
```

i checked the String SavedToSearch and is not empty :

```
    [{"name":"facebook.png","link":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blocksmanager-3c1ae.appspot.com/o/iconsStore%2Ffacebook.png?alt\u003dmedia\u0026token\u003d19837141-7476-4ae4-9d1a-066ed8aa512a"},
{"name":"eraser.png","link":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blocksmanager-3c1ae.appspot.com/o/iconsStore%2Fbutton-23968_960_720.png?alt\u003dmedia\u0026token\u003d99e00ecd-c7b5-4dc0-9969-ea0aa9e400df"},
{"link":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blocksmanager-3c1ae.appspot.com/o/iconsStore%2F580b57fcd9996e24bc43c514.png?alt\u003dmedia\u0026token\u003d21fb21e4-2d10-4e98-b226-7387b0639cb1"},
{"link":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blocksmanager-3c1ae.appspot.com/o/iconsStore%2Feraser.png?alt\u003dmedia\u0026token\u003de7f5c133-7161-45e7-a063-467e6d31a3a1"},
{"name":"instagram (1).png","link":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blocksmanager-3c1ae.appspot.com/o/iconsStore%2Ffiles.png?alt\u003dmedia\u0026token\u003d6e814321-df5d-44e5-a7bf-415d2b6271d6"}]
```

Comment: Can you add the listMap data?

Comment: @BaranBursalı you mean the whole data i past here or what the (keys) im using ?

Comment: @BaranBursalı i added the data bro

Answer (score 0):

the problem was very easy, after trying and trying i found that in my ArrayList in two items was missing the key name, i don't know how, but this was my problem and bcz that i got the above error
this is the solution of my problem, maybe it can help someone

and this code is very useful, short and work perfectly, and show the result to ListView or gridview directly.
use it in your app and thanks